# Filter all the items with cost minus the averages returns one row only

Tags: sql

Before doing implementation I always test my queries. So I created [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97a33/2).

I basically have a table with ids and cost and I want to find the difference between the actual cost and the average:

```
CREATE TABLE Items (itemId VARCHAR(10), cost INT);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (1,1);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (2,2);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (3,3);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (4,4);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (5,5);
INSERT INTO Items VALUES (6,6);
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT itemID, cost-AVG(cost) FROM Items
```

however returns the first row only. Tips?

Comment: It's returning two columns for me.

Comment: @roryap, I think he meant `first row` instead of column

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion would be to store the average in a variable then execute your query

```
SELECT @avg := AVG(cost) FROM Items;

SELECT itemID, cost-@avg FROM Items;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/97a33/20

Comment: But why does it only return one row?

Comment: I'm really not sure. Perhaps it's a bug with mysql, I'd expect it to either display all the results, or to fail. This is completely unexpected behaviour from where I'm sitting right now.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT itemID, cost-(SELECT AVG (cost) FROM Items) FROM Items
```

unless you want to store the avg in a variable